# Decomposing Semisimple Perverse Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, abelian-categories

Assume $\mathbf{G}$ is an algebraic group over an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ for some prime $p>0$. Let $\mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$ be the category of all $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$-constructible perverse sheaves on $\mathbf{G}$ where $\ell>0$ is a prime different from $p$. Now assume $K \in \mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$ is a semisimple object. Recently I saw the following way to decompose $K$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the endomorphism algebra $\mathrm{End}_{\mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}}(K)$ of $K$ then for any finite dimensional $\mathcal{A}$-module $E$ we define $K_E = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(E,K)$. We then have $K_E \in \mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$ and is simple if and only if $E$ is simple. We then have a canonical isomorphism (in $\mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$)

$$K \cong \bigoplus_E (E\otimes_{\mathcal{A}} K_E)$$

where the sum runs over a set of representatives from the isomorphism classes of simple $\mathcal{A}$-modules.

Now this idea is not unfamiliar. In the representation theory of finite groups one frequently uses the same idea to decompose induced representations. However here I am slightly confused as to why $K_E \in \mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$? My initial thought was that $\mathscr{M}\mathbf{G}$ is an abelian category so using the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem one could transport this question to a question in the category of modules for some ring, where it is clearly true. However I am not sure that this really works. Is this simply a fact of perverse sheaves?

Does anyone know of a good reference to read about the above decomposition? Or is this just some mild rewording of the fitting correspondence?

Comment: Just to say that I asked the same question on Mathsoverflow where it was answered.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124006/decomposing-semisimple-perverse-sheaves